# Value of passed integer always resets back to default value

Tags: java, android

`Bal` keeps resetting to 0.

```
Continue = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnContinue);

Continue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent startIntent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, Mainmenu.class);
        int Bal = Integer.parseInt(Balance.getText().toString());
        int MonthlyTarget = Integer.parseInt(Target.getText().toString());
        startIntent.putExtra("intBalance", Bal);
        startIntent.putExtra("intTarget", MonthlyTarget);
        startActivity(startIntent);
    }
});
```

**Another Activity** :

```
Intent startIntent = getIntent();
int Bal = startIntent.getIntExtra("intBalance", 0);

int MonthlyTarget = startIntent.getIntExtra("intTarget", 0);
Intent RecordExpense = getIntent();
int Expense = RecordExpense.getIntExtra("intExpense", 0);
Intent RecordIncome = getIntent();
int Income = RecordIncome.getIntExtra("intIncome", 0);

TextView tvResult=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResult);
tvResult.setText(Bal +"");
if(getIntent().hasExtra("intIncome")) {
    Bal=Bal+Income;

    tvResult.setText(Bal + "");
}
if(getIntent().hasExtra("intExpense")) {

    Bal=Bal-Expense;
    tvResult.setText(Bal + "");
}
```

Whenever i put `5` as Balance, and `3` as expense, I expected output to be `2`. But the actual output is `-3`

Comment: use a debugger during runtime, that's much easier then guessing here where or when data is changed

Comment: Why you're providing default value to Bal and what is value of Bal in Activity ?

Comment: +ashish Bal is an input from the user.

Comment: getIntExtra(String, int)in Intent cannot be appliedto(String) will pop up if I don't put a default value

Comment: besides using a debugger - which I highly recommend as it's the fastest and most professional way for programmers!!! - you can use a different default value and check if this is considered, e.g. use 7, so if the output is 4 you know that changes for the balances value haven't bean considered in your code. But one more time, use a debugger ...

Comment: yes, I tried changing the value and it changed the results. But I don't know how to make the default value Bal, which is an input from the user

Comment: `int Bal = startIntent.getIntExtra("intBalance", Bal);` in this intent what default value have you passed ?

Comment: Tried that, it came up with an error: Varriable 'Bal' might not have been initialized

Answer (score 0):

You're putting 0 in the `Intent` for "intBalance", instead of putting the value `Bal`.

```
Continue = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnContinue);

Continue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent startIntent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, Mainmenu.class);
        int Bal = Integer.parseInt(Balance.getText().toString());
        int MonthlyTarget = Integer.parseInt(Target.getText().toString());
        // Change 0 to Bal
        startIntent.putExtra("intBalance", Bal);
        startIntent.putExtra("intTarget", MonthlyTarget);
        startActivity(startIntent);
    }
});
```

P.S - 
Try to follow naming conventions, although it might seem inconsequential, it's easy to miss simple things when variable names look like class names.

Also, don't unnecessarily create variables like `startIntent`, `RecordExpense` & `RecordExpense`. `getIntent()` already gives you access to the intent, you don't need to get and store a reference to it in a variable everytime.

Comment: Tried this, When i displayed the Balance, it displays correctly, however, after adding income or expense, Bal will keep becoming zero, so Bal=0+Income / Bal=0-expense

Comment: Income and Expense shouldn't even be printed, since you don't put any intent extra for them. Are you sure you're looking at the correct activities?